# Keeping SafeFileHandle alive

Tags: c#, handle

FileStream closes its underlying handle when it is disposed or finalized. If a FileStream is defined as a local variable in a function and the function returns its SafeFileHandle, might the FileStream be GC'd thus closing the handle, or can I rely on the handle remaining open?

What can I do to ensure that it remains open?

Comment: @HansPassant Do you mean that the FileStream won't be GC'd or that the FileStream won't call Close on the handle?

Comment: Oh, wait.  You must call DangerousAddRef() inside the method that returns the handle so the FileStream finalizer can't close it.  And a corresponding DangerousRelease() once you are done with it.  Be sure the latter method is always called, belongs in a finally block.

Comment: @HansPassant, i deleted my comment because i forgot to mention that he has to clone the SafeFileHandle, but it didn't fit into the allowed comment length. Hence i deleted my comment to write it anew...

Comment: You could obtain/create a SafeFileHandle first, manually incrementing its reference
count through the aptly SafeFileHandle method named **Dangerous**AddRef method. Then create a copy of the SafeFileHandle, using the actual handle value from the original SafeFileHandle.
The second copy of the SafeFileHandle is being passed to the FileStream constructor (this second SafeFileHandle object will still be disposed when the FileStream closes, however the underlying file handle will not be destroyed because its reference count has been incremented manually before). (contd....)

Comment: (...contd.) After the FileStream has been closed, you can continue working with the original SafeFileHandle. But remember, it is important that you decrease its reference count again manually (through the equally aptly named SafeFileHandle method **Dangerous**Release) and before finally disposing the original SafeFileHandle.
As the the method names imply, such an approach is frought with dangers and risks and easy to get wrong. Thus i recommend you do not do it that way...

Comment: Alternatively, if you start with the FileStream object (i.e., you don't start with a SafeFileHandle before using the FileStream), you can obtain the original SafeFileHandle from the FileStream object. Then proceed as described above: increase the handle reference count, create a copy of the SafeFileHandle object, etc...

Comment: @elgonzo Would you care to post that as an answer?

Comment: @elgonzo What's the point of cloning the SafeHandle? If I'm incrementing the ref count anyway, why not use the original.

Comment: Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation of [SafeHandle.Dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h5yzadk(v=vs.110).aspx) is somewhat unclear: _"Call the Close or Dispose method when you are finished using the SafeHandle object. The Close method **leaves the SafeHandle object in an unusable state.**"_ That sounds to me that you cannot reliably continue using the SafeFileHandle of the FileStream after the FileStream has been closed/disposed (remember that the SafeFileHandle object owned by the FileStream will also be disposed when the FileStream is closed). (contd...)

Comment: (...cont.) The purpose of Incrementing the handle reference count is to let the underlying Win32 handle survive the disposing of the FileStream's SafeFileHandle object. Not sure if you could safely use that SafeFileHandle object after it is being disposed, but from the MSDN documentation it doesn't sound so. Side note: There is also a constructor for SafeFileHandle where you can specify whether a SafeFileHandle should take ownership of a native handle or not, but i do not know precisely what SafeFileHandle will do or not do to a native handle when not taking ownership...